# Correct fixture for plasterboard that has another board behind it

Tags: drywall, hanging, hardware

I'm trying to put up a whiteboard on a plasterboard wall. I am screwing the holes from one end into a stud, but the other end does not line up with a stud. I therefore planned on using [wallmates](https://www.buildex.com.au/products/general-fasteners-rivets-and-tool-accessories/27-plasterboard/152-wallmates/). However, when I tried putting a wallmate in, I hit a second board *behind* the plasterboard.

As best I can tell, it's some kind of wood, quite thin. I drilled through it and tried to put the wallmate in again, but it just won't go and started to pull the plasterboard outwards.

Can anyone tell me what the second board might be (I'm in Australia, if that helps)? It's a study, so wasn't really expecting anything other than gyprock. Also, what fixture would be best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get other fixings that "spread" behind the panel like a "star" which will work with thicker boards...

This is a supplier in the UK, you probably have an equivalent in Oz...

[One supplier](https://www.screwfix.com/c/screws-nails-fixings/plasterboard-fixings/cat840020#category=cat840020&page_size=20&page_start=20)